Превращение строки в переменную
Изучал способы форматирования и наткнулся на такую штуку :
test = 'Name'
exec('{0} = {1}'.format(test, 10))
a = Name # Python жалуется на Unresolved reference 'Name' При этом код воспроизводится без ошибок.
print(a) # Вывод: 10  Где в данный момент хранится переменная Name?
print(Name-5) # Вывод: 5
print(test) # Вывод: 'Name'

Первый вопрос, что это такое и почему это вообще работает?
Вот аналогичная запись с помощью %-форматирования :
exec('%s = %d' % (test, 10)) # Работает так же как и метод .format() - без проблем.

А вот аналогичная запись с помощью f-форматирования почему-то уже не работает :
exec(f'{(test := 10)}') # Эквивалентная запись с помощью f-форматирования выдаёт NameError: name 'Name' is not defined. Did you mean: 'name'? То есть как и должно работать.

Собственно второй вопрос, чем f-строки отличаются от других видов форматирования при воспроизведении вышеописанного кода? Почему только здесь не работает?

Приведите полный текст ошибки. Проверьте, какая строка генерируется последним способом. По идее exec одинаково должен работать, если строка одинаковая.

exec(f"{test} = 10") прекрасно работает по аналогии с первыми вашими вариантами.

А это точно сам оригинальный python жалуется? А не какая-нибудь надстройка, интеллектуальный редактор, среда разработки или линтер? К примеру, и flake8, и pylint, будут выдавать ложные жалобы, типа, "x.py:3:5: F821 undefined name 'Name'"

@Serge3leo Ну да, если код работает, то жалуется явно либо IDE либо линтер )

А давайте попробуем не делать exec, а напечатаем ваши строки. И в конце ещё напечатаем значение переменной test:
test = 'Name'
print('{0} = {1}'.format(test, 10))
print('%s = %d' % (test, 10))
print(f'{(test := 10)}')
print(test)

Вывод:
Name = 10
Name = 10
10
10

Ой как интересно. Первые два exec выполняют действие Name = 10. А последний ваш exec выполняет то, что возвращает действие test := 10 после того, как его результат преобразован в строку. Если бы вы написали test = 10, то сразу бы поняли, в чём ошибка. И я подозреваю, что вы так и сделали, и только после этого поменяли = на :=, потому что так было написано в подсказке в ошибке:

SyntaxError: f-string: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?

То есть тут сначала делается действие test := 10, а потом уже то, что получается при этом присваивании через "моржовый оператор", пытается выполниться через exec.
Кстати, отдельно непонятно, как вы умудрились в этой строке получить ошибку с "Name". Извольте предоставить полный трейс ошибки, меня терзают смутные сомнения, что код был какой-то другой у вас при этой ошибке. Текущее содержимое переменной test в этом действии совсем никак не участвует, поэтому "Name" там не откуда взяться.
Резюмирую. Не важно, как вы сгенерировали строку, с помощью какого стиля форматирования, exec всегда работает одинаково, если строка одинаковая. Чудес не бывает. А вот операторы x = y и x := y работают немного по-разному. И обычное присваивание вы не сможете написать в f-строке при выводе переменной. Но если сделаете такую же строку, как и предыдущие, то всё будет как раньше, см. комментарий strawdog.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\skorp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\PycharmProjects\TEST\Exeperement s .replace().py", line 87, in 
a = Name # Python жалуется на Unresolved reference 'Name' При этом код воспроизводится без ошибок.
^^^^
NameError: name 'Name' is not defined. Did you mean: 'name'?

Прошу прощения за ожиданиe, выше привёл полный путь ошибки. Вы абсолютно правы, в приведённом мной фрагменте кода с f-форматированием  test := 10 возвращает совершенно другое значение. Код написан в PyCharm, он и жалуется.@CrazyElf
